# Fatal Error when executing a Makefile

Tags: unix, makefile, object-files

I am currently working on an assignment that requires me to build a Makefile that

- creates an include directory
- copies math330.h file into the include directory
- create a lib directory
- compile the .c files in trig and exp as object files
- make a library
- install the library to the lib directory
- compile the cli program against the include and library directory

So I have most of the coding down for this, but I keep getting errors for when i try to put the .o's for the trig functions in the include folder. The error is

```
trig/cos330.c:1:10: fatal error: 'math330.h' file not found
```

This is just the last part i need help with! Can someone give me hints about what I can do? Thanks!

```
all:
    mkdir -p ./include
    mkdir -p ./lib
    cp math330.h ./include
    gcc -l ./include/ -c trig/*.c
    gcc -l ./include/ -c exp/*.c
    mv *.o ./lib/
    ar r libmath.a lib/*
    mv libmath.a lib/
    gcc -l ./include/ cli/cli.c -L ./lib -lmath -lm

clean:
    rm -rf include
    rm -rf lib
    rm a.out
```

Comment: The `-l` option looks wrong.  You want `-I` and/or maybe `-L`?

Comment: That's definitely not a good way to create a `makefile`.  Please read some introduction to writing makefiles, or find questions here on SO — there are plenty to choose from .  And please don't go around deleting questions as soon as you get an answer; it is not a recipe for long-term popularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option to specify an include directory is capital-I (`I`), not lower-case L (`l`).

```
gcc -I ./include …
```

The lower-case ell indicates a library name.  Given `-l ./include`, the poor linker would have a schizophrenic time looking for a library `lib./include.a` or `lib./include.so` to link with (possibly in the `./lib` directory), and it probably wouldn't find it.  But it doesn't get that far.